# LanguageCode in dialogflow JSON not working on Actions on Google

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am using dialogflow JSON to send response to the user upon receiving request but when using the languageCode parameter in JSON, the response is shown correctly in dialogflow simulator but not in AoG simulator.
The languageCode "**en**" is not working because different language tags is available for it.(https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/language) But the languages having single language tag such as **Danish** is working correctly.

Following is the code.

```
 if(request.body.queryResult.languageCode === "da"){
    // The following code is working
    } else if(request.body.queryResult.languageCode === "en"){
    // not working on AoG simulator but working in dialogflow simulator as en has different language tags such as en-AU,en-US,en-IN etc.
    } else if(request.body.queryResult.languageCode === "en-IN" || request.body.queryResult.languageCode === "en-GB"){
    // the following code is also not working on AoG simulator but working on dialogflow
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dialogflow sends these as all lower case codes: "en-us", "en-in", etc.

Probably better if the input is from Actions on Google is to look at `request.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.user.locale` which uses the correct locale encoding: "en-US", "en-IN", "es-409", etc.

Comment: Thanks again @Prisoner for the help :)

Comment: Just trying to do my part to help all of us write awesome code.